# Convert COUNTIFS to SUMIFS

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I currently have a formula which counts the number of rows that meet a particular condition in my spreadsheet.

```
=COUNTIFS(E:E,"<>",F:F,">="&TODAY())
```

As there are numbers within these rows, how do I count the value in them instead?

I've tried

```
=SUMIFS(E:E,"<>",F:F,">="&TODAY())
```

but Excel tells me I have not entered enough arguments, what am I missing?

Comment: So far your formula specifies the criteria. Which cells would you like to sum? [This is how SUMIFS works](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/sumifs.php)

Comment: @loannis - I am trying to sum the valuses in column E:E

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I used to add the values of the rows that have the date greater or equal to today's date:
`=SUMIFS(A2:A32,A2:A32,">="&TODAY())`

And to count the days greater or equal to today's date you can use `=COUNTIFS(A2:A32,">="&TODAY())`

Is this what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

To sum E:E based on the criteria in a countifs simply replace `=countifs(` with `=sumifs(e:e,`.

```
Sub sumifsCountifs()
    Dim fnd As Range, parm As Variant, tmp As String

    With Worksheets("sheet6")
        .Cells.Replace What:="=countifs(", Replacement:="=sumifs(e:e,", LookAt:=xlPart, _
                       SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False
    End With
End Sub
```